# Elisp suppress "Select coding system" when write buffer to file

Tags: emacs, elisp

I write my function. In this function I insert some data to buffer and then write this buffer to file. Here my code snippet:

```
          (set-buffer my-buffer-name)
          (set-language-environment "UTF-8")
          (setq make-backup-files nil)
          (write-file (expand-file-name my-file-name my-current-dir))
          (kill-buffer)
```

But every time when try to write to file, the elisp prompt:

**Select coding system (default raw-text)**

How I can set coding system (e.g. utf-8) to not prompt me every time when run my function?
Thanks.

Comment: what are `save-buffer-coding-system` and `buffer-file-coding-system`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `coding-system-for-write`, or `buffer-file-coding-system`
instead of using `set-language-environment`.

PS. Generally speaking, you should use the lowest-level function possible in
your code (e.g., help for `next-line` explicitly recommends that one use
`forward-line` in code instead).

In your case, you might want to use `basic-save-buffer` or even
`write-region` instead.

PPS. You should probably use `with-current-buffer` instead of `set-buffer`.

Comment: "coding-system-for-write" - it' work. Thanks. Qustion: How I can understand that one function is lowest-level than another function?

Comment: `C-h f` will give you `*Help*` buffer; read the doc, then click on the source file name and see the `defun`. it can be intimidating at first, but you will find it more and more instructive as you learn.